# c++ - test a pointer

Tags: c++, arrays

I am writting a method returning a `double*`. However, I would like to base another method behavior on output from this method. I would like to have

```
if (methodReturningArray()==0)
{
    this_behavior();
}
else
{
    this_other_behavior(methodReturningArray());
}
```

Is it appropriate then to have `methodReturningArray()` returning either the 'initialized' or 'build' `double*` and if this `double*` could not be appropriately be initialized or build, returning like that

```
double* new_array ;
return new_array ;
```

?

In other words, the `double*` output plays also role of a boolean to check whether some property is completed so that the `double*` output can be built.

Thanks and regards.

Comment: I can't see any question here, could anyone *point* me to it?

Comment: Is it ... [?], forget the ? . Excuses.

Comment: It's more that we don't know what you're asking. Your question is worded strangely, and we don't know what you want help with. Can you rephrase it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To indicate that something that you return by pointer has not been initialized, use `return NULL`. And check for it with `if(double* d = method())` (or in any other fashion you like).

However, this is not your (or my) grandfathers C++ and you should only write something like this, when you absolutely have reason to do so. I would prefer to return either a `std::array` or `std::vector` by value wrapped and throw an exception if the behavior that leads to initialization failure is somehow exceptional. If failing to initialize is part of the idea I'd wrap the return value in a `boost::optional`. But probably I'd write something that takes an `OutputIterator` to not force any particular container on my client.

Notes on disaster: `double* d; return d` will leave your client with a pointer that points to random memory. There is no way for her to figure out if has to be `deleted[]` or if it is valid. Always initialize your pointers.

Code snippets:

```
// outputiterator
template<typename OutputIterator>
void myFunc(OutputIterator o) {
  // fill stuff in
  if(someThing) {
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    {
      *o++ = 23;
    }
  } else {
    // leave it empty
  }
}

// client calls like:
std::vector<double> v;
myFunc(std::back_inserter(v));
if(!v.empty()) {

} else {

}

// exception
std::vector<double> myFunc() {
  std::vector<double> v;
  if(someThing) { v.push_back(23); return v; }
  else throw std::runtime_error("Nargh!");
}

// client
try {
  auto v = myFunc();
} catch(std::runtime_error err) {

}

// optional
boost::optional<std::vector<double>>
myFunc() {
  std::vector<double> v;
  if(someThing) { v.push_back(23); return v; }
  else return boost::optional< std::vector<double> >();
}

//client 
auto v = myFunc();
if(v) {

} else {

}
```

Comment: I disagree; there is absolutely no reason to use silly wrappers or even Boost in such cases, it only convoltutes your code, makes it more verbose and compiles slower by templating it more (especially under gcc which is not exactly fast when it comes to template processing), or even EH which just adds tons of useless runtime and black magic when unwinding.

Comment: @q66 `optional` is certainly not what is going to hurt your compile times too much and it is not too verbose. I'd prefer not having to `delete[]` things that others `new` and you also get into problems as soon as you need to change the allocator with things written like that. But that argument is really too long and have been thought often enough. There is merit on both sides and it's a question of your goals.

Comment: in fact, including almost any Boost component is gonna hurt your compile times, as Boost is stuffed with interdependencies, thus it has to expand a lot of code. I don't really think this is of any real benefit. As for deleting, it's fine in very most of cases. I can see a use for i.e. refcounting in several cases where manual handling is likely to be error prone, but that's rare.

Comment: @q66 I've added some examples. I don't think my options are that verbose given the added safety. I'm sure this is not going to convince you but gives me a clear conscience to have shown my point.

Comment: I still don't think it's of any use. You're still basing your claims around the assumption "someone will make the mistake". Yes, they probably will. But then they'll open gdb, look "ah, this line", and immediately see what's required to fix it. Easily fixable mistake in simplistic code > convoluted code trying to prevent any sort of unsafe behavior.

Comment: Your optional example is throwing rather than returning. boost::optional seems to disable RVO, and I'm not sure if they've updated it to take advantage of move semantics yet. Returning a vector could be expensive without RVO or move.

Comment: @bames53 Fixed `return/throw` mixup. Thanks for the hint on `optional`. I haven't seen a compiler that wouldn't perform RVO on the `vector` or inline the function. Do you have a concrete example in mind? This is one of the situations RVO was made for.

Comment: @pmr Last I tried, with 1.47, it didn't work; http://pastebin.com/K9j9JJqj Replacing the `optional<Foo>` in the return type with `Foo` changes the output from "ctor copy-ctor dtor dtor" to "ctor dtor". It may have been fixed since then.

Answer (score 0):

You got three ways, basically.

1) On error, return NULL. Then you can do boolean checks without issue, and it's sufficient in very most of cases.

2) Return boolean, and handle the double* output using a reference or a pointer argument like this:

```
bool methodReturningArray(double **out) { *out = ...; return true; }

double *out;
if (!methodReturningArray(&out)) this_other_behavior(out); else ....
```

3) Throw an exception - IMO kinda convoluted and unuseful.

Returning uninitialized pointer won't allow you to do boolean evaluation on it, and it's dangerous, as such pointer will be assumed dangling pointer afterwards.

Comment: I really think there are better idioms in C++ to handle such situations by now (`boost::optional`, return by value).

Comment: @pmr, I don't really think so, there are practically no benefits in doing that, and I can think of several downsides. I'm not really fond of the "modern" C++ style, IMO it just overcomplicates stuff for absolutely no reason.

Comment: If you think it's for "no reason", have a look at the bugs in the "array and string handling" category here: http://www.viva64.com/en/a/0079/. *All of them* are caused by not using "modern" C++ style. Personally, I find this embarassing: we, programmers, are still making the mistakes of 30 years ago today. Pray tell, how will the user of this code know the size of the array that the pointer points to? You can claim you don't like and don't need it all you want, but you can't claim it's for "no reason".

Comment: C++ is not a safe language, you'll always make mistakes, memory leaks, and other errors, the whole point is to keep it easily debuggable, and in very most of cases, segfaults and leaks are. If you wanna keep safe, either go managed, or use a safe native language like D.